# Twitter typeahead returning Undefined

Tags: coffeescript, twitter-typeahead

I have been working around lately with [the Twitter typeahead jQuery plugin](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).  It is mostly working, but it gives me 'Undefined' as the search result.

Here is my folder.js.coffee:

```
 $(document).ready ->
  console.log("searchhhhh");
  haunt = undefined
  repos = undefined
  repos = new Bloodhound(
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    limit: 10
    prefetch: 
        url: '/auto_search.json',
        filter: (list) ->
            $.map list.results, (auto) ->
                { value: auto }
    )
  repos.initialize()
  $('#auto_search').typeahead null,
    name: 'repos'
    displayKey: 'value'
    source: repos.ttAdapter()
  return
```

[image: jQuery]

[image]

Comment: Can you open up your browser debug tools, look in the Network tab, then capture the result of the query to `auto_search.json` and add it to your question?

Comment: I'm very new to JS and jQuery. I'll upload , see if it's enough.

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere.  I'm looking for the contents of the query, though.  Something that looks like this:  http://i.imgur.com/wz7NAHd.png

Comment: Followed this , https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
$(document).ready ->
  console.log("searchhhhh");
  haunt = undefined
  repos = undefined
  repos = new Bloodhound(
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name')
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    limit: 10
    prefetch: 
        url: '/auto_search.json',
        filter: (list) ->
            $.map list.results, (auto) ->
                { value: auto }
    )
  repos.initialize()
  $('#auto_search').typeahead null,
    name: 'repos'
    displayKey: 'name'
    source: repos.ttAdapter()
  return
```

Comment: To be clear, the only change is you changed **value** to **name** in the call to *Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace()* and in the *displayKey* attribute of the second argument in the call to *typeahead()*